# How to get the accurate number of drawn triangles per frame with Nanite in Unreal Engine 5?

Tags: unreal-engine5

This is something I have been trying to understand for quite some time. I'm using Unreal Engine 5.

I have a scene comprising a grid of Nanite-enabled objects only (nothing else in the scene). The raw triangle count of the whole set of objects is about 2.3 billion. When I check the total number of instanced triangles (Sum Tris, the tooltip informs that it is the triangle count of all mesh occurrences), the Statistics window reports 26 million triangles no matter how the camera moves (i.e., regardless of objects in camera view). When I check Triangles Drawn (under RHI) in Profiler of Session Frontend, the average of a 10s camera movement in the grid is given to be a mere 580. I think this 580 doesn't make any sense. And since the total number of instanced triangles is constant through the whole 10s camera move, it cannot be tied to the number of drawn triangles either.
So how can I get the accurate number of drawn triangles per frame with Nanite in Unreal Engine 5?